# How To Validate Phone Numbers in Redux Framework

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, preg-replace

I'm trying to `validate` a phone number field but the available options other than text won't work since people may use dashes and parentheses to enter their number.

I've tried `preg_replace` but I'm still not seeing error messages when entering incompatible data, e.g. an 'x' characters entered into a text field which should only accept an number value.

Besides a pop-up appears say that:

> There was a problem with your action. Please try again or reload the
>   page.

```
array(
    'id'       => 'sz-header-contact-phone',
    'type'     => 'text',
    'title'    => __( 'Phone number', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'subtitle' => __( 'Enter your phone number here.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'validate' => 'preg_replace',
    'preg' => array(
        'pattern' => '^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$',
        'replacement' => 'no numbers'
    ),
    'msg'      => 'Please enter correct phone number',
    'placeholder' => 'Enter your phone number here.'
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
Hung The.

Answer (score 0):

may use preg_quote() before parsing your string.